# "It had not been working as I thought" vs. "It was not working as I thought"?

Tags: phrases, past-tense

I want to convey that I recently discovered that a software code was not working like I thought it was working...I'm not sure how to phrase it correctly.

Which A phrase goes with which B phrase?

A1. I discovered today that the code was not working

A2. I discovered today that the code had not been working

B1. like I thought it was working.

B2. like I had thought it was working.

B3. like I had thought it had been working.

Answer (score 2):

You may say: I've  just discovered that the code is not working as I expected.

Your suggested sentences actually don't fit together and are a bit too wordy.

Answer (score 0):

They are all valid, but the meaning differs.

A1B1. I discovered today that the code was not working like I thought it was working. - you made the discovery today, code was not working in the way you thought, something changed between the point of the discovery and now

A2B1. I discovered today that the code had not been working like I thought it was working. - code was not working in the way you thought, then something changed, you thought it was always working.

A1B2. I discovered today that the code was not working like I had thought it was working. - code was not working in the way you previously thought it was working - however the way you thought the code worked had, at some point before another point in the past, changed.

A2B2. I discovered today that the code had not been working like I had thought it was working.  - the code was, until some point in the past, not working in the way you thought. Then something changed. You had, until some point in the past, thought that the code was working in a particular way. At some other point in the past this also changed.

A1B3. I discovered today that the code was not working like I had thought it had been working. same as A1B2 but you had thought that the code had been working from some point in a previous past to the point you stopped thinking that way

A2B3. I discovered today that the code had not been working like I had thought it had been working. Combination of A2B2 and A1B3.